# HighChart Column chart, render portion of column with color from corresponding zone

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to figure out how to render a section of each column in a simple, single series, column chart with multiple colors. Using series.zones:

```
                series: [
                    {
                        name: "Mod",
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        data: seriesData,
                        zones: [
                            { value: 101, color: '#1D681B' },
                            { value: 121, color: '#ECC518' },
                            { color: '#D50D0D' }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

I can get each column to be a different color based on the zone that the y value is within.
In my example above the zone are:

- 0 through 100 should be green
- 101 to 120 should be yellow
- 121 and above should be red

The above works to an extent, but looks like the following:

[image: What I can achieve]

However, what my boss wants is something like this:

[image: what my boss wants]

Can this be achieved using highcharts?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with stacked columns, https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked. You need to juggle the numbers, e.g. your 7th column with value of 125 has values 100, 20, 5 in the series' object array element data[6] index.

Comment: @PeterThoeny so I would use an array of three values per year? I.e...
`series: [{ name: '2012', data: [82, 0, 0] }, ... { name: '2017', data: [100, 15, 0] }, { name: '2018', data: [100, 20, 5] }, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of zones you can use stacked columns. Below is a simple example of how you can automatically calculate series structure:

```
const steps = [100, 20];
const data = [42, 100, 96, 120, 110, 90, 140];

const series = [{
  color: '#1D681B',
  data: []
}, {
  linkedTo: ':previous',
  color: '#ECC518',
  data: []
}, {
  linkedTo: ':previous',
  color: '#D50D0D',
  data: []
}];

data.forEach((dataEl, i) => {
  let rest = dataEl;
  let counter = 0;
  let value;

  while (rest > 0) {
    value = steps[counter] < rest ? steps[counter] : rest;
    series[counter].data.push({
      x: i,
      y: value
    });
    rest -= value;
    counter++;
  }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  yAxis: {
    reversedStacks: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3h6o0ncg/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/stacking-charts

Comment: This sort works, but the tool tips show for each of the three series but I just need the total value for each column. Here's what it is showing when hovering over the middle: https://i.imgur.com/KDzjOSi.png

Comment: Hi @Ken Hadden, You can configure the tooltip to show only the total value. Please check this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dv0mu4rk/

Comment: thanks. I ended up stuffing the total value into the `costom` property of the `Highcharts.PointOptionsObject` and referencing that from my custom `tooltip.pointFormat`.